# Access token validation failure. Invalid audience, office 365 Graph API

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, office365

Sorry I am at a bit of a loss trying to set up the graph API.
My end goal is app only access.
When I try to auth I get the error 'access token validation fail. Invalid audience.

My code

````
import requests
tenant = 'widgetsinc'
token_request_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}/oauth2/v2.0/token'.format(tenant)
auth_payload = {
                    'client_id': 'deaf-beef-cafe',
                    'scope': 'api://deaf-beef-cafe/.default',
                    'client_secret': 'hunter2',
                    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
                }


x = requests.post(token_request_url, data=auth_payload)
token = x.json()
print(token)

url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
payload={'Authorization':token['access_token']}

x = requests.post(url, headers=payload)

print(x.json())
exit()```

The result of print(token)
````

{
'token_type': 'Bearer',
'expires_in': 3599,
'ext_expires_in': 3599,
'access_token': 'REMOVED'
}

```
the result of print(x.json())
```

{
'error': {
'code': 'InvalidAuthenticationToken',
'message': 'Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.',
'innerError': {
'date': '2023-01-25T00:38:48',
'request-id': 'removed',
'client-request-id': 'this also removed'
}
}
}```

my permissions for my app in the web ui
[permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWMO9.png)

Comment: You need to change your **scope** to `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` to call Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> { 'error': { 'code': 'InvalidAuthenticationToken', 'message': 'Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.', 'innerError': { 'date':'2023-01-25T00:38:48', 'request-id': 'removed', 'client-request-id': 'this also removed' } } }

The above error occurs when you pass the incorrect scope, or your token has the wrong audience, to call the **`Microsoft Graph API`** in your environment. According to [MS-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token), to get an access token you need pass `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` in scope.

I tried with same code using scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` with same api permission  to get all user got an error:

**Api permission:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import requests
tenant = '<tenant-id>'
token_request_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}/oauth2/v2.0/token'.format(tenant)
auth_payload = {
                    'client_id': '<client-id>',
                    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
                    'client_secret': '<client secret>',
                    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
                }


x = requests.post(token_request_url, data=auth_payload)
token = x.json()
print(token)

url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
payload={'Authorization':token['access_token']}

x1 = requests.get(url, headers=payload)

token1=x1.json()
print(token1)
```

**Console:**

[image]

To get all user you need to use **`User.read.all`**  with application API permisson.

**API permission:**

[image]

**Console:**

After adding API permission to the application, the code executed successfully with all user.

[image]

**Reference:**
[List users - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Comment: error_description: 'AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation.